# Epplus generate invalid document after using condition

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using `Epplus` for generate a xlsx file, all working well before that I added this code:

```
var address = new ExcelAddress("G2:G5");
        var condition = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(address);
        condition.Style.Font.Color.Color = Color.Red;
        condition.Formula = string.Format("IF(G{0} < 25, 1, 0", 1);
```

essentially I'm trying to apply a different color for each cell, based on the value contained in the cell.

The file is generated correctly, but, when I open it `Excel` say that the file is corrupted.

As you can see I used as address `G2:G5`, but I also need to know how can I add a range of column between G to Y, I've a number of rows variable so I don't know the exact number to specify.

Someone knows what's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: That's an invalid formula

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you need proper syntax. You are missing a closing brace at the end of your formula.

```
                                                     |
                                                     V

condition.Formula = string.Format("IF(G{0} < 25, 1, 0)", 1);
```

Comment: my condition not working, but with your fix now the file isn't corrupted, anyway, how can I set a different font color of each cell based on the value in it?